Creating derivative layer based on other layers in QGIS
Let's say I have multiple vector layers in QGIS, and their fields are as follows:
Layer 1: ID NORTHING EASTING ELEVATION NOTE
Layer 2: PID SPC_NORTHING SPC_EASTING Z_NGVD29 COMMENTS
Layer 3: POINT NORTH EAST ELEV COMMENT
Is there a way to make a new dynamic layer which sources its attribute table data from the above 3 layers to unify the data?
Into something for example:
Layer 4: SOURCE ID NORTH EAST ELEVATION NOTE
I would like the newly created layer to be dynamic so that the data source of layers 1, 2, and 3 can be updated (keeping the same schema of course) and it dynamically updating layer 4.

Hi destruct50, welcome to GIS stack exchange. So if I understand correctly, you have 3 vector layers in QGIS, which you'd like to use to generate a fourth ?  And you want it to be dynamic, i.e. if you update the one of the original layers it should update the generated layer ? What format are your original layers (shp/gpkg/postgres) ? It sounds like you want to create a 'view' based on a series of joins between the original layers. There are essentially two ways to create joins, 1) via a common attribute and/or 2) by their geometry.

In the original three layers are there any common values ? What are the geometry types and what is the spatial relationship ? (do they overlap / does one layer (polygon) contain another (points) ? We need a bit more information

You can do this using a Virtual Layer and an SQL UNION operation on your layers, taking care to rename columns to the same thing.
For example I have two layers called "this" and "that". The "this" layer has a column called "this", and the "that" layer has a column called "that". To create a virtual layer with a "v1" attribute that comes from both layers, I use this virtual layer SQL:
select that as v1,  geometry from that union 
  select this as v1, geometry from this

I should have named the layers differently to the columns for less confusion but basically you create SQL that looks like:
 select ID as ID, NORTHING as NORTH, EASTING as EAST,  ELEVATION , geometry from layer1 
  UNION
 select PID as ID, SPC_NORTHING as NORTH, SPC_EASTING as EAST, Z_NGVD29 as ELEVATION, geometry from layer2 
  UNION
 select POINT as ID, NORTH as NORTH, EAST as EAST, ELEV as ELEVATION, geometry from layer3

Basically: QGIS Virtual Layer to make a layer defined by SQL; SQL UNION to combine rows of tables; SELECT a AS b to rename columns to the same schema.

You can define parameters with an SQL query to combine your source layers by creating a new virtual layer.
Layer>Create Layer>New Virtual Layer
Then define your SQL query.
You can define your sql query using the UNION ALL command, and rename the fields to match as you go:
`SELECT
'Layer1' AS SOURCE, 
"ID" AS ID, 
"NORTHING" AS NORTH, 
"EASTING" AS EAST, 
"ELEVATION" AS ELEVATION, 
"NOTE" AS NOTE 

FROM
"Layer1"
UNION ALL
SELECT
'Layer2' AS SOURCE, 
"PID" AS ID, 
"SPC_NORTHING" AS NORTH, 
"SPC_EASTING" AS EAST, 
"Z_NGVD29" AS ELEVATION, 
"COMMENTS" AS NOTE 

FROM
"Layer2"

UNION ALL
SELECT
'Layer3' AS SOURCE, 
"POINT" AS ID, 
"NORTH" AS NORTH, 
"EAST" AS EAST, 
"ELEV" AS ELEVATION, 
"COMMENT" AS NOTE 

FROM
"Layer3";`

The UNION ALL command combines the result set of two or more SELECT statements (allows duplicate values). You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union_all.asp
This creates a dynamic layer and your new layer should reflect any changes made to the source layers as it keeps querying them.
